# How to read a line from output of the shell script and delete that file

Tags: shell, sh

I have script which shows the files that has to be deleted from the directory .Output is visible on the command prompt.So I have to read those lines which consists of the path of the file  from command prompt  and now run a new command by using the path  as new argument to the command such that it deletes those files .So how can this be done .

For ex the files to be deleted can in be in almost 5 levels of the directories.

Comment: Are you getting absolute path of the file? or just file names?

Comment: Look at (search) bash *positional parameters*. If you are giving the filenames to deleted on the command line, then in your script `$1` is the first argument `$2` the second, etc... So `[ -f "$1" ] && rm "$1"` for the first file, etc.. If you are taking the argument from `stdin`, then you will need to `read` the value. You need to provide more detail, it is almost impossible to tell if you are taking command line parameters of input from `stdin`.

Comment: @rajuGT I am getting the absolute path of the file.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  I want to pass the values by reading it from stdin .

Comment: Ok, in your script, you will set up a `read` loop, `while read -r line; do [ -f "$line" ] && printf " %s - will be deleted\n" "$line"; done` (where it is just printing which file will be delete now). You can replace the `printf` with the `rm` call when you have tested further to insure it is doing what you need. If you will provide a few lines of sample input, I can help further.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via piping the output from the script into a new command, e.g:

```
/path/to/script.sh | xargs rm
```

I've made a few assumptions here. First, names of files are given using full paths, or relative paths with respect to the cwd (e.g. not just the filename) and second, the script prints out each file on a new line.

If the script only returns the filename, and no path, can you guarantee that all files with the name should be deleted? If this is the case, you can do the following

```
/path/to/script.sh | awk '{print " -name " $1}' | xargs find . | xargs rm
```